# Name of a foliation on an open subset of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, foliations

To a representative $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)$ of an element in $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ we associate
the point $\tau=\frac{b+id}{a+ic}$ of the Poincaré upper half-plane.
If the complex lattice $\Lambda=\mathbb Z(a+ic)+\mathbb Z(b+id)$
has only a unique pair of minimal nonzero vectors, the initial element in $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ can be recovered from $\tau$ and from the slope $\lambda$ of a minimal vector in $\Lambda$.
A generic element of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ is thus encoded by a generic geodesic $\gamma$ of $\mathbb H$ passing through a generic marked point $\tau$ with slope $\lambda$. (The pair $(\tau,\lambda)$
can of course be considered as an element of the quotient $\mathbb H\times(\mathbb S^1/\{\pm 1\})$ of the unit tangent bundle of $\mathbb H$).

This defines a foliation on an open subset of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ by fixing the geodesic $\gamma$ and varying $\tau$
along $\gamma$ as long as the corresponding lattice $\mathbb Z+\mathbb Z\tau$ has
a unique pair of minimal vectors.

*What is the name of this foliation? Where has it been studied?*

**Complement:** the geometric version of this foliation has a sort of continuous (but non-differentiable) extension: A sheet of this foliation is a piece of a geodesic which is either an open halfgeodesic or an open segment of finite length. Finite-length segments end at the familiar infinite $3$-regular tree $T$ (consisting of arcs of finite lengths corresponding to all lattices having at least two pairs of vectors of minimal length) of the $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$-tesselation of $\mathbb H$. Two such sheets giving rise to the same limit lattice at $T$ can be glued
continuously along $T$. This gives rise to sheets which are infinite piecewise geodesic paths of $\mathbb H$. Such sheets are thus geodesics which are 'rotationally refracted' at the tree $T$ (they go through $T$ but change direction). More precisely, a point $t$ on an open edge of $T$ is the starting point of two vertical half-geodesics into the cusp of $\mathbb H\backslash\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$. These two cuspidal geodesics together with $T$ cut the tangent space at $t$ into four cones with angles $\alpha,\alpha,\pi-\alpha,\pi-\alpha$.
Equiangular cones are related by reflection along $T$. The 'rotational refraction' at $t$ is then induced by rotations
of angles $\pm \alpha,\pm(\pi-\alpha)$ exchanging pairs of equiangular cones. There are thus
discontinuities along $T$ and along the two 'cuspidal' geodesics at $t$.

A sheet of infinite length (corresponding to a geodesic going into the cusp of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)/\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ can either be continued on a similar sheet on the other side of $T$ or on the singular tree $T$. Such sheets have thus no natural extension. (They correspond to
discontinuities of the 'rotational refraction' sketched above.)